# how to store selected checkbox values in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, checkbox

I want to store selected `checkbox` values in `ArrayList`. There is five `checkbox` if I select three then they will store on `ArrayList`. I used  `String []ad = new String[5];` is it write on not to store the value of `checkbox`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
CheckBox android, java, python, php, unity3D;
Button submitButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    android = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.androidCheckBox);
    android.setOnClickListener(this);
    java = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.javaCheckBox);
    java.setOnClickListener(this);
    python = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pythonCheckBox);
    python.setOnClickListener(this);
    php = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.phpCheckBox);
    php.setOnClickListener(this);
    unity3D = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.unityCheckBox);
    unity3D.setOnClickListener(this);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("ArrayList Values*******",mList.toString());
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.androidCheckBox:
            if (android.isChecked()) {
                mList.add(String.valueOf(android.getText()));
                Log.e("Android*******",mList.toString());
            }
            break;

        case R.id.javaCheckBox:
            if (java.isChecked()) {
                mList.add(String.valueOf(java.getText()));
                Log.e("Java*******",mList.toString());
            }
            break;

        case R.id.phpCheckBox:
            if (php.isChecked()) {
                mList.add(String.valueOf(php.getText()));
                Log.e("PHP*******",mList.toString());
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pythonCheckBox:
            if (python.isChecked()){
                mList.add(String.valueOf(python.getText()));
                Log.e("Python*******",mList.toString());
            }
            break;

        case R.id.unityCheckBox:
            if (unity3D.isChecked()){
                mList.add(String.valueOf(unity3D.getText()));
                Log.e("Unity*******",mList.toString());
            }
            break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `List` and add values when your click events are fired:

```
final List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
mList.add("Your value");
```

**Note**: consider to implement `onCheckChangeListener` intead of `onClickListener` to handle your checkbox selection events.

Comment: we can use ArrayList but I am new on android so can you tell me that how to add ArrayList.

Comment: I have done this please check my edited code. Now I need when someone do uncheck, the value of checkbox will be removed from ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not quite correct.

I strongly recommend creating the array when the user presses `submitButton`. Otherwise, if they check some boxes, and either

1. Rotate the screen, or
2. Put the app in the background and the Activity gets destroyed by the system (You can simulate this by selecting the "Don't keep Activities" option in Developer Options)

When they see your UI again, it will be correctly re-created - all the boxes the user has checked will still be checked, but your array will be empty!  I recommend something like

```
submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String []ad = new String[5];
        if (android.isChecked()) {
            ad[0] = (String) android.getText();                
        }
        if (java.isChecked()) {
            ad[1] = (String) java.getText();                
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

If you care about `ad` outside the context of submitting the user's choices, the best practice is to save it in the `Bundle` in `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {}`
and fetch and set it in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){}`. This way you will not loose data even on orientation change, or on the system destroying your Activity. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817321/android-programming-saving-array-using-onsaveinstancestate) for details on how to do that.

Comment: Whenever a user clicks the button your array will be reset, so you will lose previous stored data...

Comment: It will not, as the state is stored in the UI itself. Whenever the user clicks `sumbitButton` the code checks the state of every checkbox and creates the array based on the current state. I am suggesting you no longer write anything to the array in your `switch` statement, but only in the `submitButton` click listener.

Comment: Doing this: String []ad = new String[5]; within onClick callback, you create a new array instance...

Comment: Depends on what the asker wants to do with the array - the question did not specify this. I assumed the array has no utility beyond the submission code. Otherwise, it will need to be created outside the click listener, and persisted using `Activity.onSaveInstanceState` - however, the question does not mention if this is necessary.

Comment: I just want to send selected checkbox values to server when someone click submit button

Comment: @VikasGodiyal Then the easiest thing would be to do as I suggest, which is to create the array on every click of the submit button. Then you will not need to worry about rotations/lifecycle things - feel free to ignore that in this case.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer So what should I do.

Comment: Does the code I posted in my answer make sense to you? Basically, don't write anything to the array in the checkbox click listeners, and instead create the array when submit is clicked, as shown in the code in the answer. That's all you need to do.

Comment: It is lengthy process when we have n number of checkbox

Comment: From the performance standpoint, it would not be, even if you have hundreds (although your onCreate would not be happy). In any case, if there is a huge number of checkboxes here, I'd say the UX concerns would be much more substantial than anything else .

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer I have done this please check my edited code. Now I need when someone do uncheck, the value of checkbox will be removed from ArrayList

Comment: Your code doesn't handle rotations or lifecycle events.

Comment: The code you posted will not work if you check some checkboxes, rotate the screen, then press submit. In the best case, you will have an empty list. In the worst case, you app will crash because `mList` is `null` and you can't call `toString` on `null`.